# How should I use RReliableTopic in redisson?

Tags: publish-subscribe, redisson

In the following sample code, RTopic works perfectly but the RReliable topic does not invoke the listener method when I publish a new message to the topic.
I've also tested publish and subscribe methods in different projects but it doesn't make any difference. Redisson version 3.14.0

```
Config redissonConfig = new Config();
redissonConfig.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://192.168.1.1:6379")
                .setUsername("test").setPassword("test")  ;
    
RedissonClient redissonClient = Redisson.create(redissonConfig);
    
MessageListener<Object> listener = (channel, message) -> {
      System.out.println(message);
};
**RTopic** topic = redissonClient.getTopic("mytopic");
topic.addListener(Object.class, listener);
System.out.println(topic.countSubscribers());
topic.publish("RTopic works");
    
**RReliableTopic** rtopic = redissonClient.getReliableTopic("rtopic");
rtopic.addListener(Object.class, listener);
System.out.println(rtopic.countSubscribers());
rtopic.publish("RReliableTopic works");
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce it with 3.15.4 version. Do you see any error in log?

Comment: No, I do not see any error message.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me even with the newer version. I think there should be an issue with our Redis server setup. we use a ha proxy as a load balancer and put some Redis server behind it. I should test it without a ha proxy.